# XAML Page With Grid And Button

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid which will take up most of my Xamarin.Forms Page, and I want to add a button below the grid. My issue is that I am using the below syntax to add the button, however the button fills the entire page.

What do I need to change so that the button appears directly below the grid?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="XF.Pages.AEI" >
    <ContentView Content="{Binding ApprovedUserGrid,Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="0,30,0,0"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding OkayCommand}" Text="Okay" TextColor="White"  
            FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
            BackgroundColor="#088da5" /> 
</ContentPage>
```

This is C# for my grid (not where I actually bind, but the creation)

```
        private Grid _Grid;

    public Grid TestGrid
    {
        get { return _Grid ?? (_Grid=new Grid()); }
        set
        {
            _Grid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
I edit code to read like this, and there are no errors, but I do not see my button on the page?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="XF_Login.Pages.ApproveUsers" >
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30" Spacing="40"> 
       <ContentView Content="{Binding ApprovedUserGrid,Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="0,30,0,0"/>
       <Button Command="{Binding OkayCommand}" Text="Okay" TextColor="White"  
            FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
            BackgroundColor="#088da5" /> 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Where's the grid?? Maybe you tried to create a custom control and confused wrapping it with a contentpage instead of contentview?

Comment: @NickKovalsky - i edit OP to show the GRID creation. If I need to include where I actually bind the data to the grid I can do that as well.

Comment: Still do not see where to you layout the grid and the button. You just shown controls and not the page or code where you layout them..

Comment: a ContentPage can only have a single child.  You need to enclose your Grid and Button in a Layout container

Comment: @Jason - see my edit...I must still be missing something

Comment: try assigning a HeightRequest to your ContentView, it is probably pushing your Button off of the page

Comment: @Jason - if I set a heightrequest=15 on the ContentView the button is above the grid. I want the button below the rid.

Comment: then there is something else funny going on, without seeing all of your layout it's hard to say what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="XF_Login.Pages.ApproveUsers" >
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="30" Spacing="40"> 
       <ContentView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Content="{Binding ApprovedUserGrid,Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="0,30,0,0"/>
       <Button Command="{Binding OkayCommand}" Text="Okay" TextColor="White"  
            FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center"  
            BackgroundColor="#088da5" /> 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```